# Use Active Storage without Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

There is a case we want to use the Active Storage without Rails. We are using activemodel, activejob in Gemfile. we would like to use activestorage in our ruby application.

Is it possible to configure and use activestorage without rails? if so can anyone please give us the suggestion how to configure and use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a fools errand. ActiveStorage is an extremely opinionated solution that was designed from the ground up as an integrated part of Rails and is also developed inside the Rails codebase. There are other solutions like CarrierWave that are framework agnostic and provide the same features and which won't give you a massive headache.

Comment: actually looks like no direct dependency są you could try

Comment: @eudaimonia no - not in the gemspec but you don't have to look far to find [direct Rails dependencies](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cf4fa5caf39f1271d3f8c4c9774e874430ea0f68/activestorage/config/routes.rb#L3). Getting it to work without Rails is going to be extremely difficult if not impossible.